# Add to a variable when a JCheckBox is selected

Tags: java, jframe, jcheckbox

I need to write an application that allows the user to choose insurance options in JCheckBoxes. Upon selecting a JCheckBox, I want to add the value of that option to the "TotalPrice". I initialized the totalPrice to 0, but when I try to add to it in the "if" statements, nothing happens.

```
package p3s4;

import java.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JInsurance extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    //initialize variables.
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    int hmoPrice = 200;
    int ppoPrice = 600;
    int dentalPrice = 75;
    int visionPrice = 20;
    String decimal = ".00";
    DecimalFormat moneyFormat = new DecimalFormat(decimal);
    int totalPrice = 0;
    //initialize TextFields and CheckBoxes.
    JLabel heading = new JLabel("Choose insurance options: ");
    JCheckBox hmo = new JCheckBox("HMO");
    JCheckBox ppo = new JCheckBox("PPO");
    ButtonGroup providersGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JCheckBox dental = new JCheckBox("Dental");
    JCheckBox vision = new JCheckBox("Vision");
    JTextField hmoSelection = new JTextField(hmo.getText() + " $" + moneyFormat.format(hmoPrice));
    JTextField ppoSelection = new JTextField(ppo.getText() + " $" + moneyFormat.format(ppoPrice));
    JTextField dentalSelection = new JTextField(dental.getText() + " $" + moneyFormat.format(dentalPrice));
    JTextField visionSelection = new JTextField(vision.getText() + " $" + moneyFormat.format(visionPrice));
    JTextField totalSelection = new JTextField("Total:  $" + totalPrice);

    public JInsurance() {
        super("Insurance Options");

        setLayout(flow);
        add(heading);
        providersGroup.add(hmo);
        providersGroup.add(ppo);
        add(hmo);
        add(ppo);
        add(dental);
        add(vision);
        add(totalSelection);
        add(hmoSelection);
        add(ppoSelection);
        add(dentalSelection);
        add(visionSelection);
        //Set visibility.
        hmoSelection.setVisible(false);
        ppoSelection.setVisible(false);
        dentalSelection.setVisible(false);
        visionSelection.setVisible(false);
        totalSelection.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //add listeners.
        hmo.addItemListener(this);
        ppo.addItemListener(this);
        dental.addItemListener(this);
        vision.addItemListener(this);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        //Check if boxes are selected. If they are, add price of insurance
        //option to "totalPrice" TextField.
        if (source == hmo) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                totalPrice += 200;
                hmoSelection.setEditable(false);
                hmoSelection.setVisible(true);
                hmoSelection.getParent().revalidate();

            } else {
                totalPrice -= 200;
                hmoSelection.setVisible(false);
            }
        } else if (source == ppo) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                totalPrice += 600;
                ppoSelection.setEditable(false);
                ppoSelection.setVisible(true);
                ppoSelection.getParent().revalidate();
            } else {
                totalPrice -= 600;
                ppoSelection.setVisible(false);
            }
        } else if (source == dental) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                totalPrice += 75;
                dentalSelection.setEditable(false);
                dentalSelection.setVisible(true);
                dentalSelection.getParent().revalidate();
            } else {
                totalPrice -= 75;
                dentalSelection.setVisible(false);
            }
        } else {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                totalPrice += 20;
                visionSelection.setEditable(false);
                visionSelection.setVisible(true);
                visionSelection.getParent().revalidate();
            } else {
                totalPrice -= 20;
                visionSelection.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JInsurance first = new JInsurance();
        final int WIDTH = 500;
        final int HEIGHT = 300;
        first.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        first.setVisible(true);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        first.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - first.getSize().width / 2,
                dim.height / 2 - first.getSize().height / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `nothing happens` What do you expect to happen? Do you want the value in `totalSelection ` to change?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the text of `totalSelection` yourself. This is because when you initialise it, you provide a String object which has been generated from the value of `totalPrice` at that time.

So to fix it, reset the text of `totalSelection` at the end of `itemStateChanged`

Answer (score 0):

You display the totalPrice value within the totalSelection JTextfield, but you never update the text held by the JTextField. The Java compiler and JVM are very dumb and will only do what you tell it to do. If you want the text to update, you have to explicitly call `setText(...)` on the text field when you want the update to occur.